# Is it possible to make external call from substrate contract

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot

I want to make external http calls such as (eg. RPC calls to infura) from substrate contract. Is it possible?
If possible, then suggest me ways or some code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible as such calls would be non-deterministic.

The closest thing you have to functionality like this is Offchain Workers:

- https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/offchain-workers/
- https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/offchain-operations/

But this would require you to write special logic which handles consensus about offchain data, and then additional code or features which would expose this data correctly to a contract.

I think like most oracles on existing smart contract platforms, you will want to submit a transaction to the chain which populates the data, rather than have a contract try and pull the data from the outside world.